# How to make the blue bar on the top disappear for tttableview with list datasource (program running on ios 5 beta)

Tags: three20

There is a blue bar appearing on the top of my tttableview when the program is running on ios 5 beta, it was not there if I run the program on ios 4.3.
The table is configured to use a list datasource.
Does anyone know what the problem could be? Is it the tableview api changed in someway for ios 5?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It is caused by a subtle but important change Apple made in the UITableView behavior for section headers and footers. If you implement the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: or tableView:viewForFooterInSection: delegate methods then you MUST now also implement the tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: and tableView:heightForFooterInSection: delegate methods.

The extra blank section header you are seeing is caused by returning 'nil' from the '...viewFor...' methods but not returning 0 from the '...heightFor...' methods.

Answer (score 1):

Pull down the latest code from Three20 git repository on github. They have corrected this issue with tttableview.

See this page https://github.com/facebook/three20/issues/643