# residual header space for TTTableViewController on iOS 5

Tags: three20, ios5

I have a class that inherits from TTTableViewController, and overwrites the "createDelegate" method to use the TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate instead of the default Delegate.

The problem that I am seeing right now is that there is some header space that appears before my table content (supplied by data source, of course) for iOS 5, but this isn't there on pre-iOS 5 versions.

I searched around and found this article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651367/how-to-make-the-blue-bar-on-the-top-disappear-for-tttableview-with-list-datasourc), but it doesn't quite help me as I did not overwrite tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method.

What I have noticed is that for all my TableViewControllers that have this problem, they all seem to overwrite the "createDelegate" method and return TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate, as mentioned above.

My question is: anyone ran into the same issue?  How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out.  The problem is with an old three20 library that I was using.  Once I upgraded to the latest, it was fixed.